# Use emacs or vim syntax highlighting files (e-lisp, vimrc) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vim, emacs, ide

Is it possible to somehow import emacs or vim sytax highlighting specifications in Eclipse? I tried searching but all I can find are questions about vim/emacs and Eclipse integration or other unrelated things.

Comment: what do you mean syntax hl in eclipse? eclipse has syntax hl, hasn't it? you can also define the colors of different keywords. or do you mean color-scheme?

Comment: @romanini Because I'm using an experimental language and I'd like to have syntax highlighting in an IDE. All I have however is syntax definition files in the formats I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about *that other editor*, but for Vim syntax highlighting, this is definitely not possible. Why?

- Vim syntax definitions are written in Vimscript; it would require a complete interpreter.
- Most definitions use regular expressions; no other engine implements exactly the same flavor; some atoms are unique to Vim.

If you just want similar colors in Eclipse, you can certainly re-create your Vim *colorscheme* in another editor. The output of `:highlight` gives you all defined groups and their color values.